# Can I get the median of the values accross multiple rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame

```
      Date          vix2
0  2010-01  [14, 15, 16]
1  2010-02  [19, 20, 22]
2  2010-03  [28, 40, 60]
3  2010-04  [36, 24, 30]
4  2010-05  [34, 25, 22]
5  2010-06  [24, 29, 30]
```

and I would like to get the median of N rows, where N here is 2, so I would like the result to be something like

```
      Date  median
0  2010-01     NaN
1  2010-02    17.5
2  2010-03    25.0
3  2010-04    33.0
4  2010-05    27.5
5  2010-06    27.0
```

This line of code seems to work but then I can't seem to get past the error

```
np.median(result['vix2'].values, axis=0)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

================================================================

EDIT:

The following solution worked for me, with the help of BENY and not_speshal

```
n = 2
result['new'] = pd.Series([np.median(np.concatenate(result['vix2'].iloc[x:x+n].values.tolist())) for x in result.index])
result['new'] = result['new'].shift(n-1)
```

Comment: Will each list always have exactly 3 elements?

Comment: No, it is only for this example. Each list can have up to 23 elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need `rolling` number with 2, we can do `shift`

```
df['new'] = pd.DataFrame((df['vix2'] + df['vix2'].shift(1)).fillna({0:[]}).tolist()).median(1)
Out[98]: 
0     NaN
1    17.5
2    25.0
3    33.0
4    27.5
5    27.0
dtype: float64
```

More  comment way to deal with `object` type rolling

```
n = 2
df.loc[n-1:,'new'] = [np.median(np.ravel(df['vix2'].iloc[x:x+n].values)) for x in df.index][:-n+1]
df
Out[121]: 
           vix2   new
0  [14, 15, 16]   NaN
1  [19, 20, 22]  17.5
2  [28, 40, 60]  25.0
3  [36, 24, 30]  33.0
4  [34, 25, 22]  27.5
5  [24, 29, 30]  27.0
```

Comment: HI, I will need to roll up to 12 lists, will this solution still work?

Comment: @lurence work with the 2nd method ~

Comment: @lurence you can change to `np.ravel`
`df.loc[n-1:,'new'] = [np.median(np.ravel(df['vix2'].iloc[x:x+n].values)) for x in df.index][:-1]
`

Comment: I'm really liking this solution but this broke for me on N=3 ```ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value```, could you please fix it?

Comment: @Pab ah updated ~After change the [:-1] to [:-n+1] should be fine

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'  :(

Comment: @Pab you can play around with your sample dataframe , check whether this method work or not , if it work for the sample data, you can check the diff between your real data and sample data

Comment: @Pab I have updated the post, see if the solution works for you

Comment: @lurence For some strange reason I'm still getting the same error for the second solution. But in any case, I got to replace ```np.median(np.ravel(df['vix2'].iloc[x:x+n].values))``` for ```df['vix2'].iloc[x:x+n].explode().median()``` and got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Combine values for every N (=2) rows into a single row.
2. Use `explode` and `groupby`

```
N = 2
df["values"] = pd.Series([df["vix2"].iloc[x-N+1:x+1].sum() for x in df.index])
output = df.explode("values").groupby("Date")["values"].median().reset_index()

>>> output
      Date  values
0  2010-01     NaN
1  2010-02    17.5
2  2010-03    25.0
3  2010-04    33.0
4  2010-05    27.5
5  2010-06    27.0
```

Comment: I think OP wants the answer to be generalized to N. @lurence?

Comment: HI, does this only work for combining 2 lists, because I will need to combine more than that, I just used 2 as an example.

Comment: @lurence - Edited

Comment: @not_speshal your comment is empty?

Comment: huh? I edited my answer

Comment: ohh okok, i did not notice that. thanks

Comment: @not_speshal I have just tried the new solution, and while it almost works, it seems like it is adding the values of N lists instead of concatenating said lists. I have tried to use np.concatenate as the other solution has the same issue, but to no avail.

Comment: No. `sum` concatenates the lists in the column. At least on version 1.3.4. You may need to upgrade if you're on an older version. As a simple check, `df["vix2"].sum()` outputs: `[14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 22, 28, 40, 60, 36, 24, 30, 34, 25, 22, 24, 29, 30]`

Comment: Ah I see, I'm on 1.3.5, however, I have found a working solution, and I'll update my question with it soon.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this answer assume that all dates will be different in the Date column? I'm trying to understand the answer

Comment: @Pab - Yes, it does. If not, OP could simply do `df.groupby("Date")["vix2"].sum()` before doing all the above.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a little dirty, but it covers your case fully:

```
N=2
rolling_index=[]
df.index.to_series().rolling(N).apply(lambda df: rolling_index.append(df.values) or 0, raw=False)
df['values']= [np.NaN]*(N-1)+[df.loc[i,'vix2'].explode().median() for i in rolling_index]
```

Result N=2:

```
    Date    vix2    values
0   1   [14, 15, 16]    NaN
1   2   [19, 20, 22]    17.5
2   3   [28, 40, 60]    25.0
3   4   [36, 24, 30]    33.0
4   5   [34, 25, 22]    27.5
5   6   [24, 29, 30]    27.0
```

Result N=3:

```
    Date    vix2    values
0   1   [14, 15, 16]    NaN
1   2   [19, 20, 22]    NaN
2   3   [28, 40, 60]    20.0
3   4   [36, 24, 30]    28.0
4   5   [34, 25, 22]    30.0
5   6   [24, 29, 30]    29.0
```